# Include file based on user role

Tags: php

I have a script that after a user logs in, it will determine whether he is in one of the following groups:

```
admin
user
manager
```

and based on that it will do an include based on his role. so lets say if the user is in the admin group it would be like this:

```
after login
include( "admin/index.php" );
```

That works fine, but the issue is when that page comes up any of the links in that page that should go to pages in the admin/ directory but they don't, it still assumes its in root because thats where the include is from. How do i get around that while using an include? Or is it even possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.  `include()` is not magic, but just another function.

```
set_include_path ("/path/to/the/files");

switch ($user_role)
{
case 'admin':    include("admin/index.php");         break;
case 'user':     include("meremortal/index.php");    break;
case 'manager':  include("prince/index.php");        break;
}
```

Comment: thats exactly how i am doing it, but the issue is when the admin/index.php page comes up all the links in that page think that they are in root/ instead of the admin/ directory

Comment: @BradHazelnut:  You may want to set up [include_path](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path).

Comment: ok but how would i be able to use that for what i am doing? do you have a simple example you could show me

Comment: i just tried adding that and it still does the same thing

Answer (score 0):

When your scripts are executed from different directory levels, `include()` needs to be aware of what directory level you are at in order to use paths relatively.  Instead, I usually define a constant in a config file with the absolute root path on the server, so you don't need to use relative paths:

```
const ROOTPATH = "/var/www/yoursite/";

include ROOTPATH."path/to/file.php";
```

For any `href`s on the page, you'll need to link to their absolute path as well, using a `/` at the beginning:

```
<a href='/path/to/file.php'>link</a>
```

Comment: i tried using that, but it didn't work, instead i used define, even though i still have the same issue though

Comment: exactly, and the hrefs are just plain links like this <a href="accounts.php"> but that file would only be in admin/accounts.php but for some reason when i include the file that link seems to think its in the root directory

Comment: You're looking at something a little more complicated, I think.  Take a look at my edited answer, but keep in mind that you'll need to do some validation to keep general user accounts from attempting to access files within the admin/ directory.

Comment: Im trying to prevent editing all the href links like that, is there any other possible way to fix this?

Comment: You will have to write new links accordingly.  It seems to me you're approaching the issue sideways.  Do the admin/manager pages have completely different content from the user page, or do they show much of the same thing, only with additional components/controls?  This would be a crucial consideration in determining exactly how to deal with the issue at hand.

Comment: They are very similar except for additional controls for the admin, but also the data that gets displayed is also based on the user role

Comment: I would suggest then to add conditional includes for just those unique components, inline with the page, rather than a full page for each role.  It cuts down on re-coding when a change needs to be made.  This is now fairly off-topic from the original question, and best-practices would probably dictate a different approach from the question's intent.

Comment: good idea, i like that thanks man, i think i will use that approach